# vue-konva make v-text use vars/props

Tags: vue.js, konvajs

So we have a line which works just fine

```
<v-text :config="{text: 'sampleText'}" />
```

But how to make v-text element to use vue variable/props?

```
<v-text :config="{text: {{sampleText}}}" />
```

vue doesn't like this:

```
Errors compiling template:    
  invalid expression: Unexpected token { in {text: {{sampleText}}}
```

What is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use:

```
<v-text :config="{text: sampleText}" />
```

where `sampleText` is a vue variable